# XAML: StackPanel with horizontal scroll, inner ListView with vertical scroll

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, scrollviewer

I have StackPanel with X ListViews.

Each ListView must scroll vertical.

StackPanel must scroll horizontal.

```xml
<StackPanel Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ListView MinWidth="200" Margin="5,5,5,5">
    </ListView>
    <ListView MinWidth="200" Margin="5,5,5,5">
    </ListView>
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

With this code ListViews scroll work ok.

If I place StackPanel in a ScrollViewer, ListViews scroll don't work.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try change ScrollBarVisibility properties on ScrollViewer

```
<ScrollViewer 
    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ListView MinWidth="200" Margin="5,5,5,5">
        </ListView>
        <ListView MinWidth="200" Margin="5,5,5,5">
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

[image: result]